# Hibernate throw TransientObjectException when I pass a transient object as parameter for a query after I implement the optimist locking

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I am working in a project with Hibernate Entity Manager, and everything was nice until I start to implement the optimistic lock in our entities.

For example, we have the following named query that returns the addresses of a person:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Address.findByPerson", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.person = :person")
```

In order to pass the person object to this query, we usually did something like this:

```
Person nPerson = new Person();
nPerson.setId(1);

TypedQuery<Address> query = manager.createNamedQuery("Address.findByPerson", Address.class);
query.setParameter("person", nPerson);
query.getResultList();
```

It was fine until we introduce the @Version inside the Person entity. After that, the follow exception start to occurs:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.sandboxmaven.entity.Person
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at com.sandboxmaven.main.Sandbox.main(Sandbox.java:52)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.sandboxmaven.entity.Person
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 12 more
```

I wasn't able to find any explanation in the documentation for this behavior. Sure, it's a simple thing to solve passing only the id of the Person or a managed entity as parameter. But I would like to understand why this started to occurs. Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate needs to verify that the object is not transient, otherwise it does not make sense to use it in the query.

How does Hibernate check whether an object is transient? I wasn't able to find some official documentation on this, but I looked at the source code. Part of the method [`AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/entity/AbstractEntityPersister.java) looks like this:

```
// check the version unsaved-value, if appropriate
final Object version = getVersion( entity );
if ( isVersioned() ) {
    // let this take precedence if defined, since it works for
    // assigned identifiers
    Boolean result = entityMetamodel.getVersionProperty()
            .getUnsavedValue().isUnsaved( version );
    if ( result != null ) {
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see, Hibernate will inspect the value of the `version` field (among other things) to try to verify whether the object is transient.

Since the `version` in your prototype `Person` is `null` (or other unsaved value, based on the strategy that determines what an unsaved value is), Hibernate knows the instance is transient and throws the exception. Without the versioning, Hibernate checks whether the person id is `null` (or other unsaved value, based on the strategy) to make distinction between transient and non-transient instances:

```
// check the id unsaved-value
Boolean result = entityMetamodel.getIdentifierProperty()
        .getUnsavedValue().isUnsaved( id );
if ( result != null ) {
    return result;
}
```

so it worked before you introduced versioning, because the id is not `null`.

To overcome this it is best that you pass in the id to the query as you already suggested. Or you can set the `version` to the `nPerson` prototype you use in the query:

```
Person nPerson = new Person();
nPerson.setId(1);
nPerson.setVersion(1);
```

Here we can set any version value because it is not used anyway; Hibernate will see that it is not `null` and will not consider the object as transient.